# How to implement two factor authentication over simplejwt in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have implemented authentication using simple jwt and Now I want to implement 2 factor authentication. I am using react for frontend.

2-fa will be introduced only when there is change in browser/device/ip address.

I store this information I have thee field in my user model `last_login_location`, `last_login_device`, `last_login_browser`.

To get the token:

```
class CookieTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get('refresh'):
            cookie_max_age = 3600*24*24 # 14 days
            response.set_cookie('refresh_token',response.data['refresh'],max_age=cookie_max_age,httponly=True)
            del response.data['refresh']
        return super().finalize_response(request,response,*args,**kwargs)
    
    serializer_class = CookieTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Serializer class:

```
class CookieTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        return token
    

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)
        data['mail'] = self.user.mail
        return data
```

urls

```
path('auth/token/',CookieTokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
path('auth/token/refresh/',CookieTokenRefreshView.as_view()),
path('auth/token/verify/',TokenVerifyView.as_view()),
path('auth/token/blacklist/',CookieTokenBlacklistView.as_view()),
```

I want to check for change in location/device/browser during login and apply 2-fa by sending OTP over mail.

Is there any way I can implement over this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add middleware like this.

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from user_agents import parse

class RequestInfoMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        user_agent = parse(request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', ''))
        request.browser = user_agent.browser.family
        request.device = user_agent.device.family
        request.ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '')
```

Save these details in your database(and cache also) and then check these details when the user logs in and for OTP feature you can use this module

```
pip install django-otp
```

Comment: my question is how can I overwrite `TokenObtainPairView` to send the otp and after verification send tokens.

Comment: Create a post function in View and send the OTP to the device and save the opt into the database and make another verify opt API to validate and return the token. Do you want the code?

Comment: I have one question so after checking password, I want to check for `last_login_location/browser/device` and if it does not match with db then send OTP but where should I store tokens which i received after auth so that I can send it after OTP is verified?

Comment: It totally depends on your use case and how you want to do it, I would store the token in a different table with user foreign key, and then when user tries to log in I can check the meta details like location, browser, and device in request otp API and accordingly send the OTP.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to complete this. this post was very helpful. Adding here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61769602/otp-verification-in-django-rest-framework